# Xunit not closing Selenium webdriver on test fail despite using driver.Quit();

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xunit

I am trying to convert my Selenium Nunit tests to Xunit and I am stuck on figuring driver quit.

Xunit is not closing Selenium webdriver process or chrome browser only when test fails despite using driver.Quit();.

Test looks something like this

```
  [Fact]
        public void test1()
        {
            SetupTest();
//testing something that fails
            TeardownTest();
        }
```

SetupTest

```
 internal static void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl); 
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize(); 
        }
```

TeardownTest

```
internal static void TeardownTest()
{
    try
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
    }
    Assert.Equal("", verificationErrors.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try...finally construction or implement IDisposable interface and invoke TeardownTest method inside Dispose()

```
[Fact]
public void test1()
{
    try{
        SetupTest();
        //testing something that fails
    }finally{
        TeardownTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to minimize chroom webpage for get pagesource?